# Make macro prefix and expansion

Tags: gcc, macros, makefile, gnu-make

Considering the following code:

```
all: model_aaa model_bbb model_ccc

.PHONY: all model_aaa model_bbb model_ccc

model_aaa: files/aaa.csv
    @bash ./startup/aaa.sh


model_bbb: files/bbb.csv
    @bash ./startup/bbb.sh

model_ccc: files/ccc.csv
    @bash ./startup/ccc.sh
```

Now I need to make some changes:

```
MODELS:= aaa bbb ccc
FUNCTIONS:= startup1 startup2 finalize1 postcode
all: model_$(MODELS)  # it does not convert to what I need

.PHONY: all model_$(MODELS) # it does not convert to what I need

model_%: files/%.csv
    @bash ./$(FUNCTIONS)/$*.sh #it does not do what I need.
```

When the macro `MODELS` expands, its prefix does not repeat. I also need to run all scripts `startup1` `startup2` `finalize1` `postcode` on all models `aaa` `bbb` `ccc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Makefile syntax suggests that you are already relying on GNU Make.  In that particular implementation of Make, you can obtain what you want with a pattern substitution.  The short form for this case would be

```
all: $(MODELS:%=model_%)
```

and so forth.

You can apply the same approach to your multiple scripts, by expanding to a single bash command that runs each in sequence.  There's a bit of a trick to matching the pattern-generated targets with the needed rule, but as long as you're already relying on GNU make, you might as well go all in with a pattern rule:

```
$(MODELS:%=model_%): model_%: files/%.csv
    bash -c "$(FUNCTIONS:%=./%/$*.sh; ) :"
```

**UPDATE**:
If you need to make those targets depend on the shell scripts, too, then you can do that.  You need to understand that the pattern substitution matches the *first* `%` on the left of the `=` as a wildcard, and replaces the *first* appearance on the right side of the `=` with whatever is matched.  Other `%` characters remain in the result, and may be interpreted according to the pattern rule syntax.  Thus, you can do this:

```
$(MODELS:%=model_%): model_%: files/%.csv $(FUNCTIONS:%=./%/%.sh)
    bash -c "$(FUNCTIONS:%=./%/$*.sh; ) :"
```

Given your definition of `$(FUNCTIONS)`, the expression `$(FUNCTIONS:%=./%/%.sh)` expands to `./startup1/%.sh ./startup2/%.sh ./finalize1/%.sh ./postcode/%.sh`, leaving the pattern rule to match the remaining `%` wildcards to the tail part of the name of each `model_foo` target.

Comment: Thank you. It solves a part of my question. How about expanding all bash scripts on all models?

Comment: this is a good idea however it is not extendible to dependencies. what is i need to make those bash `.sh` files as dependencies of `$(MODELS:%=model_%)` as well?

Comment: @ar2015, yes, you can make those model targets depend on the corresponding shell scripts, too.  See my updated answer.